# get Starting space in String using perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get white space and assign it to a string using `perl`.

I have a string

`$line = "       Testing purpose"`

I want to get the white space in that string and assign it to another string. 
Can any one help me here?

```
$line = "       Testing purpose";
```

`$space = "      ";` 
( This space variable will have space from `$line`.)

Comment: For me it's not clear what are you trying to achieve. What about using `my $space = " ";`? Do you really care where do you get this space from? Do you want to get a first symbol of string?

Comment: From your question, it's not clear what you have tried, what you have searched for, etc

Comment: The aim is i have to get the starting space in a line and have to use the space in inserting next line. So Both the line will start at same point!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expressions.

```
$line =~ m/^(\s*)/;
$space = $1;
```

This will match spaces and tabs, leaving original string unmodified. If you want to also remove space from original string, use this:

```
$line =~ s/^(\s*)//;
$space = $1;
```